# After logging to keycloak with react application getting 404 Page Not Found error

Tags: keycloak

After logging to keycloak with react application getting 404 Page Not Found error. The React application and keycloak server both are deployed in GCP but its working fine in local

Please Find Below Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGP4e.png)

Instead of trying local url we tried with deployed url on keycloak server Clients Tabs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDxRu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.